# Relative date and a cleaner "yesterday" & "the day before yesterday"

Tags: php, date, relative-date

I modified a script to get a relative date from a timestamp (x times ago) and I would like to tweak it to add another level of precision like "yesterday" or "the day before yesterday".

Tried this and it works but it's not very clean, do you have an idea how can I simplify the two lines after "Recent days"?

```
function relativedate($timestamp, $limit = 1209600){
    $diff = time() - $timestamp;
    $time = ($diff < 1) ? 1 : $diff;
    $times = array(
        "year"   => 31536000,
        "month"  => 2592000,
        "week"   => 604800,
        "day"    => 86400,
        "hour"   => 3600,
        "minute" => 60,
        "second" => 1
    );

    // Date limit as displayed full
    if ($limit > 0 && $diff > $limit){
        return "on ".date("d/m/Y - H:i:s", $timestamp);
    }

    // Recent days
    if ($diff > $times["day"]       && $diff < ($times["day"] * 2)-1) return "yesterday";
    if ($diff > ($times["day"] * 2) && $diff < ($times["day"] * 3)-1) return "the day before yesterday";

    // Display x time ago
    foreach ($times as $unit => $seconds){
        if ($time < $seconds) continue;
        $amount = floor($time / $seconds);
        return "since $amount $unit".(($amount > 1) ? "s" : "");
    }
}
```

Both my edit and the reply works but it's still not so clean? Trying to figure out how I can do it in another way.

Though about `strtotime("yesterday")` and `strtotime("-2 days")`?

Comment: Why not use [carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)?

Comment: @Kyslik this is just a small feature on my website, doesn't need a full library for it!

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is just not right :) that is my point here. I think your problem is that `$diff` variable can be both positive and negative; therefore subtracting from it causes you problem. Have you tried debugging at all; (`var_dump($diff)`ing)?

Comment: @Kyslik edited the question, working now but not very clean :/

Comment: I haven't understood what is what you want. Please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function relativedate($timestamp, $limit = 1209600){
    $diff = time() - $timestamp;
    $time = ($diff < 1) ? 1 : $diff;
    $value = '';
    $times = array(
        31536000 => "year",
        2592000 => "month",
        604800 => "week",
        86400 => "day",
        3600 => "hour",
        60 => "minute",
        1 => "second"
    );
    // Date limit as displayed full
    if ($limit > 0 && $diff > $limit){
        return "on ".date("d/m/Y - H:i:s", $timestamp);
    }
    // Recent days
    if ($diff >= (24*60*60) && $diff < (48*60*60)) {
        $value = "yesterday";
    }
    if ($diff >= (48*60*60) && $diff < (72*60*60)) {
        $value = "the day before yesterday";
    }
    // Display x time ago
    foreach ($times as $seconds => $text){
        if ($time < $seconds) continue;
        $amount = floor($time / $seconds);
        $value = "since $amount $text".(($amount > 1 && $text != "mois") ? "s" : "");
        break;
    }
    return $value;
}

echo relativedate(strtotime("-1 hour")).'<br />';
echo relativedate(strtotime("-23 hour")).'<br />';
echo relativedate(strtotime("-25 hour")).'<br />';
echo relativedate(strtotime("-49 hour")).'<br />';
echo relativedate(strtotime("-73 hour")).'<br />';
echo relativedate(strtotime("-1173 hour")).'<br />';
```

Result:

```
since 1 hour
since 23 hours
since 1 day
since 2 days
since 3 days
on 22/09/2015 - 21:47:59
```

Comment: I already tried this but this returns me always "yesterday" even if it's only from one or two hours.

Comment: It works fine here. Check what value has your $timestamp variable when you pass it in your function call.

Comment: Ha, sorry, my bad, the issue is if the value is MORE than one or two days. Thats returns "yesterday".

Comment: Ok, try the updated answer. It seems to work fine now.